# Multiple simultaneous updates with MongoDB/PyMongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

According to the PyMongo [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7%2B/api/pymongo/collection.html), `update()` can only update a single document at a time. Let's say I have 100 documents I want to update simultaneously. That's a lot of overhead. Is there a way to update multiple documents with a single MongoDB query through PyMongo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, you can update multiple docs with the multi option:

```
collection.update(spec, doc, multi=True)
```

This updates all matches.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific? Say that I pull 10 objects from the database, each with a unique `_id`, and I change one field in each. How do I then put those changes in the database? Bonus points for both simplicity and query efficiency.

Comment: Are each of the changes different?  If so, you'll have to do separate updates.  You can't batch them, but I doubt that being unable to send them together is a bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you! based on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-multiple-documents I was trying `collection.update(spec, doc, {'multi':True})`. Subtle but important difference. ;-)

Comment: Very late. But the accepted answer is not detailed enough to rely on. Took me few minutes to get to the right place. This is for the new people coming in here and want it in more detail with an example: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/python/update/#update-multiple-documents

Answer (score 2):

you can update multiple documents with different _id at a time by using bulk write feature available in mongodb 2.6
try this http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html

in precise you can use Ordered Bulk Write Operations which updates a bulk of records which are with different criteria.

view this for more details [Best way to read and update mongodb documents using pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485042/best-way-to-read-and-update-mongodb-documents-using-pymongo/25490502#25490502)