# Best way to read and update mongodb documents using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

iam trying to read a mongodb collection document by document in order to fetch every record encrypt some of fields in the record and put it back to database.

```
for record in coll.find():
    #modifying record here
    coll.update(record)
```

this is causing a serious problem i.e already updated documents are read again by cursor and same document is processed again in loop (same document is trying to update again)

hope this may be one of the solution to the problem.

```
list_coll = [record for record in coll.find()]
for rec in list_coll:
   #modifying record
   coll.update(rec)
```

but is this the best way of doing? i.e what happens if the collection is large ? can large list_coll causes ram overflow?
kindly suggest me a best way of doing it.

thanks

Comment: I can't think of better way so I won't fill an answer. Recommending generator over creating list of records would be probably insane since I think you would have the same problem. I would most likely use your solution, although if I were to update really large collection, I would strip records of unnecessary values while creating the list, just to save some extra space (which could prevent "ram overflow"). In case you think it is realistic scenario, you should probably take a bit of the collection at a time. (note: you could add flag to modified records and use first snippet, but w/ overhead)

Comment: yes, but my striped list also will be large that's my problem.

Comment: Okay. At least the intent is clearer. There is a better way that is not addressed as yet from my reading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the ["Bulk Operations API"](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html) from MongoDB. Mostly introduced with MongoDB 2.6, so a compelling reason to be upgrading if you currently have not.

```
bulk = db.coll.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()
counter = 0

for record in coll.find(snapshot=True):
    # now process in bulk
    # calc value first
    bulk.find({ '_id': record['_id'] }).update({ '$set': { 'field': newValue } })
    counter += 1

    if counter % 1000 == 0:
        bulk.execute()
        bulk = db.coll.initialize_ordered_bulk_op()

if counter % 1000 != 0:
    bulk.execute()
```

Much better as you are not sending "every" request to the server, just once in every 1000 requests. The "Bulk API" actually sorts this out for you somewhat, but really you want to "manage" this a little better and not consume too much memory in your app.

Way of the future. Use it.

Comment: does this initialize_ordered_bulk_op() works with pymongo 2.5

Comment: @wudpecker Bulk insert operations were introduced in pymongo 2.6 and mixed operations including updates as of 2.7. The main requirement is the server version of MongoDB 2.6 or greater, which if you already have in place then you should consider upgrading your client library as well.

Answer (score 3):

If your collection isn't sharded you can isolate your `find` cursor from seeing the same doc again after it's updated by using the [`snapshot`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-isolate-cursors) parameter:

```
for record in coll.find(snapshot = True):
    #modifying record here
    coll.update(record)
```

If your collection is sharded, keep a hash variable of the `_id` values that you've already updated and then check that list before you modify each record to ensure you don't update the same one twice.

Comment: Use [`coll.find(modifiers={"$snapshot": True})`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/migrate-to-pymongo3.html#snapshot-and-max-scan-replaced-by-modifiers) in PyMongo 3.

Answer (score 0):

Mark each record as updated, e.g. by adding a flag or by making sure that the updated field has a certain form that can be matched by a query.

Use the query to match only documents that were not updated yet, and double check each document as you iterate.

Why?

- Because the collection may be too large to manage updated IDs in a local hash
- Because your process might crash and leave the collection in a half-updated state. You may want to be able to resume it.

If this is a one-time job on a non-sharded collection, consider using a snapshot query.